# Prime Factorization With Exponents In Java

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, exponent, factorization

I'm trying to write a java code that displays the prime factorization of a number in two forms: multiplied out and multiplied out with exponents. For example, the proper output would look like this:

> Enter a number
>
> 100
>
> The prime factorization of 100 is:
>
> 100 = 2 * 2 * 5 * 5
>
> 100 = 2^2 * 5^5

Except my current code only outputs this:

> Enter a number
>
> 100
>
> The prime factorization of 100 is:
>
> 100 = 2 2 5 5

Here's what my code looks like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Factorization {
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    // user inputs variables here
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    long n = keyboard.nextLong();
    System.out.println("The prime factorization of " + n + " is: ");
    System.out.print(n+" = ");

    // solution for 1 as an input

    if(n==1){
        System.out.println("1");
    }

    // for each potential factor
    for (long factor = 2; factor*factor <= n; factor++) {

        // if factor is a factor of n, repeatedly divide it out
        while (n % factor == 0) {
            System.out.print(factor + " "); 
            n = n / factor;
        }
    }

    // if biggest factor occurs only once, n > 1
    if (n > 1){
        System.out.println(n);
    } else {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

How can I make it give the proper output?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Printing out the first form is easy, and would just require a slight modification to your code so that it would print out the `*`. The second form, however, is a bit more tricky as you can't just directly print out the factors as you obtain them, since you need to count how many times each one occurs to know their exponent. There are a few different ways you could do this, but I thought the simplest would be to use 2 ArrayLists. One of these ArrayLists would contain the bases, while the other would contain the exponents for each base. This is my implementation, and I added some comments for clarification.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Factorization{
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    // user inputs variables here
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    long n = keyboard.nextLong();
    long m = n;
    System.out.println("The prime factorization of " + n + " is: ");
    System.out.print(n+" = ");
    ArrayList<Long> bases = new ArrayList<Long>(); //ArrayList containing each unique factor
    ArrayList<Long> exponents = new ArrayList<Long>(); //ArrayList containing exponents, or the amount of times that factor is multiplied

    // solution for 1 as an input

    if(n==1){
        System.out.println("1");
    }
    // for each potential factor
    for (long factor = 2; factor*factor <= n; factor++) {

        // if factor is a factor of n, repeatedly divide it out
        while (n % factor == 0) {
            n = n / factor;
            if (!bases.contains(factor)){ //if the factor is not already in the bases list, it's unique and should be added
                bases.add(factor);
                exponents.add(1L);
            }
            else{ //if the factor is already in the bases list, increment its exponent by 1
                exponents.set(bases.indexOf(factor), exponents.get(bases.indexOf(factor)) + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    // if biggest factor occurs only once, n > 1
    if (n > 1){
        if (!bases.contains(n)){
                bases.add(n);
                exponents.add(1L);
        }
        else{
            exponents.set(bases.indexOf(n), exponents.get(bases.indexOf(n)) + 1);
        }
    }
    //printing out the first form
    for (int i = 0; i < bases.size(); i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < exponents.get(i); j++) //each base is printed out an amount of times equal to its exponent
        {
            if (i != 0 || j != 0) //making sure we don't print * before the first base
            {
                System.out.print(" * ");
            }
            System.out.print(bases.get(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print(m+" = ");
    //printing out the second form
    for (int i = 0; i < bases.size(); i++) 
    {
        if (i >= 1) //making sure we don't print * before the first base
        {
            System.out.print(" * ");
        }
        System.out.print(bases.get(i) + "^" + exponents.get(i));
    }
}
}
```

If you want to learn more about ArrayLists, I recommend you check out the official Java documentation on it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html.
I hope this helps.